# discord.js-commando TypeError: RichEmbed is not a constructor

Tags: discord.js

I want to send embed with discord.js-commando but when I send the command it says me this:

An error occurred while running the command: TypeError: RichEmbed is not a constructor
You shouldn't ever receive an error like this.

here is my code

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class EmbedCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'embed',
            group: 'util',
            memberName: 'embed',
            description: 'Embeds the text you provide.',
            examples: ['embed Embeds are cool.'],
            args: [
                {
                    key: 'text',
                    prompt: 'What text would you like the bot to embed?',
                    type: 'string'
                }
            ]
        });    
    }

    run(msg, args) {
        const { text } = args;
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(text)
            .setAuthor(msg.author.username, msg.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setColor(0x00AE86)
            .setTimestamp();
        return msg.embed(embed);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using discord.js v12+ it’s `Discord.MessageEmbed()`

Answer (score 0):

RichEmbed is called MessageEmbed in newest Versions. Renaming it should be fine.